# Remove dashes and colons in specific parts of a text

Tags: r

I have text file similar to this.

```
Section A - Blah blah
Random sentence.
Section B - Hello
Random sentence.
SECTION C - Random sentence
Random sentence.
SECTION D - Hi
Part A - Hey
PART B - howdy
Task 1: Blah
Task 2: Blah
```

I am trying to obtain:

```
Section A  Blah blah
Random sentence.
Section B  Hello
Random sentence.
SECTION C  Random sentence
Random sentence.
SECTION D  Hi
Part A  Hey
PART B  howdy
Task 1 Blah
Task 2 Blah
```

I am trying to detect the patterns in the text such as "Section", case insensitive, followed by a letter or "Task" followed by a number, and remove punctuation in that line. I was wondering how I could do this, as generically as possible.

Answer (score 4):

***EDIT:*** Adding solution by adding more checks on same.

```
fd <- read.table(text="Section A - Blah blah
Random sentence.
Section B - Hello
Random sentence.
SECTION C - Random sentence
Random sentence.
SECTION D - Hi
Part A - Hey
PART B - howdy
Task 1: Blah
Task 2: Blah", header = FALSE)


fd  %>%
gsub("(Section[^-]*)-(.*)","\\1 \\2",.) %>%
gsub("(Task[^:]*):(.*)","\\1 \\2",.)
```

Output will be as follows.

```
[1] "Section A   Blah blah\nRandom sentence.\nSection B   Hello\nRandom sentence.\nSECTION C   Random sentence\nRandom sentence.\nSECTION D - Hi\nPart A - Hey\nPART B - howdy\nTask 1  Blah\nTask 2  Blah"
```

---

---

Following may help you here.

```
gsub("-|:","",var)
```

Following is the variable's sample data.

```
var <- c("Section A - Blah blah
Random sentence.
Section B - Hello
Random sentence.
SECTION C - Random sentence
Random sentence.
SECTION D - Hi
Part A - Hey
PART B - howdy
Task 1: Blah
Task 2: Blah")
```

Comment: DOWN VOTER, please do mention reason for down vote here?

Comment: I was not the down voter, but I was wondering if this could be made more generic, so basically any word, not just "Section" or "Task"

Comment: Actually nevermind, I got it. You can just replace "Section" and "Task" with \\w

Comment: @J.Doe, please see my EDIT it fulfills your question, kindly do let me know?